# Summary Across Reports - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, report

I've got some criteria that we're surveying for our buildings. The reports are grouped by building and floor for several different sets of data (for instance info on Bathrooms, Meeting Rooms, Doors etc). Each report is for a different set (ie Bathrooms and Doors are seperate reports completely, drive from seperate queries).

These reports have math expressions such as calculating averages per floor/per building etc. I know, a lot of backstory here.

Bottom line is:

I need a way to take a field, let's say "TotalBuildingRating", which is the same across all 20+ reports, and produce a summary- a simple page saying

```
For building X: Bathroom Rating | Meeting Room Rating | Door Rating
                     80%        |        50%          |   60%
              (ValueFromBathRpt)|(ValueFromMeetingRpt)|(ValueFromDoorReport)
```

Is there a way to do this without performing the math in SQL? It's quite complex at times... I'm completely lost as to how to do this. The individual data set reports are working perfect, but I cannot summarize them in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up opening all of the summary reports in the background for each group, and referencing them in my total summary using

```
IsError([Reports]![GroupOneSumm]![SumPercent], 1, [Reports]![GroupOneSumm]![SumPercent])
IsError([Reports]![GroupTwoSumm]![SumPercent], 1, [Reports]![GroupTwoSumm]![SumPercent])
```

and so on for each sum on the other reports. Not elegant, but it's working. I can call it a "feature" that the summary also shows you the details in other windows... The `IsError()` is because if one of the other reports has no data, it comes up with an error in `[SumPercent]`. Since it's empty, its rating is 100%, thus `], 1, [`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a subreport. Create it to provide the summary you need and then drop it into the report header or footer of any other reports.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. My problem is creating that summary.

Comment: I am not sure I follow either, you do not seem to have provided any information on what goes into the summary report, other than to say it is from, say, the bathroom report. How did it get there? Do you want to convert an existing report to a summary? Do you wish to open reports in background and reference a control?

Comment: I didn't wish to reference reports in the background, but that's what I ended up doing for now.. Basically I had these summary values in other reports (say, the bathroom report and the meeting room report) and needed to provide an "All" report, which took those summary values and averaged them. So in my example above, it would look like : Building X: 80%, 50%, 60% -> 63.3% overall.